# SQL how to get previous record if dis_stat = 20

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get records that if they meet a certain condition then do not get included in the records. I can get all the records i need but when i try to then group records based on trying to eliminate that record combo i am not sure how to do that. If dis_stat = 20 then do not show that record and previous record.
Example records:

```
MEMBER : Readmit_conf_30 : Conf_num : Dis_Stat
12345                         1212       6
12345                         1213       6
12345      1215               1214       1
12345      1216               1215       7
12345                         1216       20
```

So the conf_num = 1216 with dis_stat = 20 should not show along with previous record of conf_num= 1215, readmit_conf_30 = 1216

Here is code i have to get records for this member. I have tried many ways get rid of those 2 records but no success.

Thanks for the help.

Code:

```
WITH Group1 AS (
SELECT A.MEMBER, B.SEX, B.DOB, B.LAST_NAME, B.FIRST_NAME, A.PROVIDER_ID, C.PROVIDER_NAME
, A.CONF_NUM, A.BEG_DT, A.END_DT, A.TOS_I_4, A.DIS_STAT, A.AMT_EQV,  A.AMT_PAY, A.AMT_REQ
, A.READMIT_INDEX_30, A.READMIT_30, A.READMIT_CONF_30
FROM CONFINEMENTS A 
LEFT JOIN MEMINFO B ON A.MEMBER = B.MEMBER 
LEFT JOIN PROVINFO C ON A.PROVIDER_ID = C.PROVIDER_ID
LEFT JOIN MAP_DATE_RANGE D ON D.IA_TIME = A.IA_TIME
WHERE A.CUST_OPL_MED IN ('A$*', 'B$*', 'N$*', 'P$*', 'D$*',  'Unspecified$UNK')
--AND A.BEG_DT >= '05/01/2013' and A.beg_dt <'05/01/2014' 
and A.PROVIDER_ID  Like '344428218046' --firelands regional 
and (A.READMIT_30 = 1 OR A.READMIT_30 = 0)
--AND A.DIS_STAT <> 20
AND A.MEMBER = '03732529500'  --'04644786700'
),
GROUP2 AS (
SELECT AA.MEMBER, AA.READMIT_CONF_30
FROM Group1 AA
WHERE AA.READMIT_CONF_30 > 0
--AND AA.DIS_STAT <> 20
),
select MEMBER, READMIT_CONF_30
,SEX, DOB, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, PROVIDER_ID, PROVIDER_NAME
, CONF_NUM, BEG_DT, END_DT, TOS_I_4, DIS_STAT, AMT_EQV, AMT_PAY, AMT_REQ
, READMIT_30, READMIT_INDEX_30
from group1
union 
select MEMBER, READMIT_CONF_30
,SEX, DOB, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, PROVIDER_ID, PROVIDER_NAME
, CONF_NUM, BEG_DT, END_DT, TOS_I_4, DIS_STAT, AMT_EQV, AMT_PAY, AMT_REQ
, READMIT_30, READMIT_INDEX_30
from Group3
order by conf_num
```

Comment: What release of SQL Server?

Comment: Could you try pulling in [ROW_NUMBER](http://www.sqlserver.info/syntax/row_number-how-to-use-it/) and then eliminating the dis_stat (and the sister line) through a `HAVING` clause?

Comment: I am using SQL but the tool i am using is Cognos 10.2.2. So i use sql pass thru since i know sql better then this tool.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use NOT EXISTS().. though with the code sample you provided it's hard to tell exactly where.. but in your first cte GROUP1 it would look like

```
WHERE 
    ----
    AND a.Dis_Stat <> 20
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM CONFINEMENTS c 
                    WHERE c.Conf_num = a.Readmit_conf_30 
                          AND c.Dis_Stat = 20)
```

Comment: I created another Group4 to the last select statement and then did your NOT EXISTS with a new select statement. This worked. Thank you for the help